# Serial EEPROM - Reading Manufacturer, SN and PN?

Tags: linux, eeprom

Is it possible to get any device + manufacturer's information read off a serial EEPROM itself via I2C?

Specifically, I'm looking for the device type (i.e. '24C256') but could not find any linux references on how to capture that information (if it even exists).

Thanks,
Grant

Answer (score 0):

Many chips hold that information but it is only accessible via JTAG interface (this is a tst mode interface). If the chip is part of system or PC the JTAG acces usually isn't possible.